# how do I extend django BaseDateListView

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want my view to give out objects with specific date range. How can I implement BaseDateListView ? Can somebody give me an example

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views.generic.dates import BaseDateListView


class YourClass(BaseDateListView):

    def get_dated_queryset(self, **lookup):
        return queryset with specific date range
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/views/generic/dates/#BaseDateListView

Comment: would it be like this 'def get_dated_queryset(self, **lookup):
        return Model.objects.filter(created_at__range=[from_date,to_date]) ' Can you please give me more clue. I went through the doc but couldnt understand it